# Edit a .ppam file for customizing an add-in

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I was provided an add-in for powerpoint as a .ppam file and another add-in for Excel as .xslm file. The add-in's work great, but I would like to customize them with some internal requirements.

My questions is - how to open the source code behind a .ppam file ( which I understand is a compiled version) to be able to perform the customizations.

Comment: have you tried to open IDE by pressing 'Alt+F11' in PowerPoint and searching if there is your add-in in project window? if it's created with VBA you should be able to find it there and possibly edit...

Comment: You are right! I cant find the add-in in the VBE IDE when I use Alt+F11. Does this mean the add-in was not created in VB or am I not seeing it for other reasons. I am loading the add-in each time I open a presentation. Its NOT located in C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\AddIns at the moment.

Comment: it could be created with VB.NET of C# but check it- try to expand project by clicking into cross/square icon left to add-in name. Moreover, you could check file location in PP App >> File >> Options >> Add-ins...

Comment: I actually don't even see the add-in when I hit Alt-F11 and there is not project expansion square box on the left! I know the file location, and I am double-clicking the .ppam file to load the add-in after I open PP. However, I am unable to see the code behind the ppam file. Sorry for being a novice here - I am trying to customize/create and add-in which can update notes and plots in PP from a external scripting language like R/S-plus

Answer (score 34, accepted):

If it's a PPAM file, it was created in PowerPoint from a PPTM file saved as an add-in.

While you can edit loaded add-ins "in place" for testing purposes, you can't edit then save them.  But you can export the add-in's modules then import them into a new PPTM file or copy/paste code between the two.

In order to get access to the modules/code of the loaded add-in, you need to make a registry change.

IMPORTANT:  Quit PowerPoint first.

Then go to:

`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\14.0\PowerPoint\Options`

(That'd be for PPT 2010; substitute 16.0 in place of 14.0 for PPT 2016/2019/2021/365 and later, 15.0 for PPT 2013, 12.0 for PPT 2007 and so on ... there's no 13.0)

Add a new DWORD value:  `DebugAddins = 1`

Start PPT again; now your loaded add-ins will appear in the VBA IDE.  If they're not password protected, you'll be able to open them, edit for test purposes, and export the modules or copy/paste for use in a new PPTM file.

Be sure to export any modules you've changed fairly often; if you quit PPT or it crashes, you'll lose any changes since the last save.

Comment: Thanks Steve! I can at least see the code now. I will start working on customizing the code to suit my requirements!

Comment: This is an old answer, I know. But you saved my life. Thanks.

Comment: By the way, the same trick -- sort of -- works in Mac PowerPoint.  Instead of changing the registry, you change the Prefs file for PowerPoint.  If you're familiar with the usual reg settings for PPT/Windows, it's not too difficult to work out the correspondence between that and the Mac's Prefs file and make the necessary changes.

Comment: Worth noting, if you create the value while PowerPoint is running, and close it, it will reset the DWORD to 0.  If you go the RegEdit and press F5 to update the values you can see that the change is made.  Just change it back to 1 after closing all instances of PowerPoint, and then re-open it.

Comment: Yes!  Thanks for pointing that out, @BrainSlugs83.  The same is true of most if not all of the registry entries that PPT uses. It reads them at startup, holds them internally, then writes them back either as they're changed or at shutdown, so any changes we make while it's running will get overwritten.

Comment: @BrainSlugs83  Yep. That's why I wrote that you should quit PowerPoint first.  But I've edited the original post a bit to emphasize that better.  By the way, the same is true of most of PPT's registry settings.  It reads them at start up, maintains them internally for the duration of the session, seems to write back any changes immediately, then writes back the whole works at shutdown, so any changes you make to the registry while it's running will have no effect and will get overwritten.

Comment: The closest reg key I found was `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\16.0\PowerPoint\Options`. I added the options subkey, and it was under `HKLM` not `HKCU`. Unfortunately it did not work.

Comment: As far as I know (though I haven't tested) the value must be created under HKCU. It works on every version of PPT back to PPT 97. Depending on the mix of "bitness" you have between Windows and Office, you might need to start in HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Wow6432Node and follow that down to Software, etc.

Answer (score 3):

### If you also want to copy/modify a custom ribbon

In addition to Steve Rindsberg's perfect solution, you can do the following to transfer custom ribbon properties:

1. Start off from the original .ppam file and the modified .pptm file as described in Steve's post. In the following, I'll refer to them as `OLD.ppam` and `NEW.pptm`.
2. Open both `OLD.ppam` and `NEW.pptm` using [Office RibbonX Editor](http://github.com/fernandreu/office-ribbonx-editor/releases/latest).
3. Under the `NEW.pptm` file, add a `customUI14.xml` entry by clicking Insert --> Office 2010+ Custom UI part.
4. Copy the contents from the `customUI14.xml` part of the `OLD.ppam` to the one within `NEW.pptm`.
5. To get the icons: Extract the `OLD.ppam` file in the Windows Explorer using 7zip or similar. You'll find the images within the extracted folder `OLD/customUI/`.
6. Back in Office RibbonX Editor, click on `customUI14.xml` within `NEW.pptm`. Then, insert the Icons from the Insert menu. You can select all items at once.
7. Save the file `NEW.pptm` in Office RibbonX Editor and close it.
8. To create an add-in, open `NEW.pptm` in PowerPoint and save it as `NEW.ppam`.

Comment: This hasn't received enough love! The VBA is only half the outcome ladies and gents - the XML is key if you want to be able to access what you change!