# Edit a .ppam PowerPoint add-in and save changes

Tags: vba, powerpoint, office-addins

I have a very useful PowerPoint add-in in a .ppam format. I used the following method ([Edit a .ppam file for customizing an add-in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17569893/edit-a-ppam-file-for-customizing-an-add-in)) to open it in VBA and slightly modify to better suit my needs. I would like to save the changes now, so that they are in effect whenever I open PowerPoint with that add-in. However, when I click 'File -> Save' in VBA Editor and restart PowerPoint, the changes I made are no longer there.

How do I save them?

Answer (score 1):

You can't.  You can either copy/paste from the edited modules/forms/classes into new modules/forms/classes in a PPTM file or export each of the modules/forms/classes and then import them into a PPTM.

Answer (score 0):

I am maintaining one PowerPoint Add-in myself for a long time.
My way of doing it:

1. keeping the master file in ".pptm", and always maintain it there
2. as soon as the master files opens (can be hooked in Ribbonloaded event), it'll disable the running add-in
3. I developed a button to release current .pptm file replacing the .ppam add-in, so as long as I want to publish again, I'll click it.