# How to copy button/ribbon from PowerPoint AddIns (.ppam)

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I have an AddIn №1 (.ppam format) and now I want to modify it. I have already copied all info like modules and forms to a new file (.pptm). However I have no idea how to copy ribbons from the old AddIn. When I open AddIn №1 by XML editor there no XML code. When I unzipped AddIn there 3 XML files but I don`t understand what to do with the,. It looks like there no files of this ribbons and buttons. I will be glad to see any advice.
Does this means that the ribbon was created not in XML-editor like MSO ribbon?

I want to copy buttons/ribbon to a new file and update the AddIn.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Edit a .ppam file for customizing an add-in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17569893/edit-a-ppam-file-for-customizing-an-add-in)

Comment: @taller's link points to the answer (read all the way to the bottom).  Short version is that in the root folder of the unzipped PPAM, there'll be a customUI folder and in it, one or two XML files and possibly images etc.  It's the customUI folder and its contents that define the ribbon customization for the add-in.