# How can I recover vbaproject.bin from my corrupt powerpoint.pptm file

Tags: vba, powerpoint, ms-office, corrupt-data

I have a .pptm file with 70 hours of code work in it. It has become corrupted and I have no backup (very stupid I know!). What I do have is the .ppam which was generated from a slightly earlier version of it. When I open the VBA editor, I can see all the modules of code, but when I try to open them nothing happens. There does appear to be information in the vbaproject.bin file. I am running Windows 10.

Does anyone know how I can recover this work (preferably the code in the .pptm file, if not is it possible to revert the .ppam file?)

I have tried exporting the modules, but when I do no file appears in the selected folder. I also downloaded two pieces of software that claim to be able to help (bit recover vba macro remover and vbp), but to no avail. My search is continuing, but any help here would certainly be greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 1):

You'll be able to recover your code from the PPAM, so long as you can load it in PowerPoint. There's an article here on SO that describes how to do it:

[Edit a .ppam file for customizing an add-in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17569893/edit-a-ppam-file-for-customizing-an-add-in/17573427#17573427)

Now promise you'll make backups from now on, ok?  :-)

Comment: My ppam is not fully up to date, but this has recovered 95% of my code, so thank you! Still looking for a solution on the remaining 5% but not as important. I promise I'll do backups haha!